# Probability theory task

Tags: probability

The team has two trainee analysts. Each trainee receives the correct answer in 14 out of 17 cases. To be more confident in an important decision, the Manager decided to give the same task to both analysts at once: if both get the same answer, the Manager will use it, and if the answers are different, he will choose one of them at random. How much does this method increase the Manager's chances of making the right decision?

As I understand, there can be two situations: First, situation when two trainees gives an equal right answer.Probability=14/17 * 14/17. And second situation is when one trainee gives right answer and one-incorrect answer and after that Manager takes correct answer: 14/17 * 3/17 * 1/2 . Am I right? If yes,how we can estimate how this method increases manager's confidence?

Comment: What if they both give the wrong answer?

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Yeah,they can give two equal wrong answers and two different wrong answers

Comment: Not quite, but very close.  You need to multiply the second factor by $2$.  You're using the probability that Trainee $1$ gets the right answer and Trainee $2$ gets the wrong answer.  Multiplying by $2$ gets you the probability that either trainee gets the right answer and the other gets the wrong answer.  If I've done the arithmetic correctly, it doesn't change the manager's confidence that his decision is correct.

Comment: @RobertShore But...If one will give right answer and another trainee wrong answer, manager will choose one randomly.  And who exactly gives the right answer(first or second trainee) is not important...  I do not understand why we need to multiply by 2

Comment: @ТимурНазаров Because if you don't you're undercounting the frequency with which exactly one trainee gives the right answer.  To see this, calculate the probability that both trainees give the wrong answer.  Now note that the sum of the three figures ($0, 1, 2$ trainees give the wrong answer) has to be exactly $1$.

Comment: From a modeling perspective, the most important thing to notice is that most likely the answers of the trainees are not independent! They likely have much better results on "easy" problems and may fall into the same "traps" on hard ones. So while the problem can be answered under "independence assumptions", those are not a good approximation for "the real world scenario".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting problem in the sense that it can be solved under much more general assumptions than I initially thought. The first thing to do is to abstract away the $\frac{14}{17}$ probability for a correct answer by each trainee to a $p$ probability with $0 \le p \le 1$. But in addition:

1. No need to assume the answers can only be yes or no, there can be multiple different right answers and multiple different wrong answers.
2. No need to assume the correctness of the answers is independent between the trainees. They could be mind-sharing aliens that always give the same answer, or (if $p < \frac12$) they could never get a right answer at the same time.

If the set of all problems for them to solve is the square, the Venn diagram would look like this

[image: Probability Venn diagram]

The red and green ellipses show the problems where Trainee 1 and Trainee 2 give the correct answers, resp. They have the same size and there may be a common area where both give correct ansers.

$t_1$ is the area/probability that only Trainee 1 gives a right answer, same for $t_2$ and Trainee 2. The area/probability for both to give a corrent answer is $c$.

We know that

$$t_1+c=p=t_2+c$$

because each equality says that one trainee gets it right with probability $p$. So we see immediately that $t_1=t_2$, which I denoted with $d$ in the diagram.

The "mind sharing aliens" scenario would be $c=p, d=0$. OTOH, $d=p, c=0$ would be the 2 trainees that never get it right together. The assumption that the answers are independently correct would lead to $c=p^2, d=p-p^2=p(1-p)$. But as I said, none of that is needed to solve the problem!

We have 4 cases to distinguish, with T1, T2 donating the 2 trainees and R/W them being right or wrong.

**T1:R, T2:R**

This case will happen with probability $c$. No matter if they give the same or a different correct answer, the manager will pick one of their answers, so it will be a correct answer. So the manager's decision will be correct with probability $1$ in this case.

**T1:R, T2:W**

This case will happen with probability $t_1=d$. The manager will pick one answer at random, so it will be correct with probability $\frac12$.

**T1:W, T2:R**

This is the "mirror image" of the previous case. It happens with probability $t_2=d$ and the manager will be correct with probability $\frac12$.

**T1:W, T2:W**

Neither trainee is right, so the problem comes from the area outside both of the ellipses. The probability for that is $1-t_1-c-t_2=1-c-2d$. No matter if they give the same or a different incorrect answer, the manager will pick one of their answers, so it will be an incorrect answer. So the manager's decision will be correct with probability $0$ in this case.

---

Let's make a quick check that everything is OK: The 4 probabilities for the 4 cases should add to $1$ if the case distinction is correct (no overlap, nothing left out). That turns out to be true:

$$(c) +  (d) + (d) + (1-c-2d) =1$$

So now we can find the probability $p_M$ that the manager is correct with their scheme, by muliplying the probability of each case occuring with the probability of the manager getting the correct answer there, and adding them all up:

$$p_M=(c\times1) + \left(d\times\frac12\right) + \left(d\times\frac12\right) + ((1-c-2d)\times0)= c+\frac{d}2 + \frac{d}2 =c+d=p.$$

So it turns out the probability is independent from how $c$ and $d$ actually look like, and it is the same probability as a trainee alone to get it right. So the scheme is not better (or worse) than just having 1 trainee solve the problem, which is a bit surprising, I'd say.

---